# Enable mode if file content contains a matching string

Tags: regular-expressions, major-mode

I would like to enable `rjsx-mode` whenever a file I open contains a specific string, or a regex like `import.*react` for example. Is there a way to do something like this in emacs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I would like to enable [some mode] whenever a file I open contains a specific string, or a regex

This is exactly what `magic-mode-alist` is for (there is also `magic-fallback-mode-alist` if you want the filename mode matching to take precedence).

In your case `(add-to-list 'magic-mode-alist '("import.*react" . rjsx-mode))`.

```
magic-mode-alist is a variable defined in ‘files.el’.
Its value is nil

  This variable may be risky if used as a file-local variable.

Documentation:
Alist of buffer beginnings vs. corresponding major mode functions.
Each element looks like (REGEXP . FUNCTION) or (MATCH-FUNCTION . FUNCTION).
After visiting a file, if REGEXP matches the text at the beginning of the
buffer, or calling MATCH-FUNCTION returns non-nil, ‘normal-mode’ will
call FUNCTION rather than allowing ‘auto-mode-alist’ to decide the buffer’s
major mode.

If FUNCTION is nil, then it is not called.  (That is a way of saying
"allow ‘auto-mode-alist’ to decide for these files.")
```

Comment: magit -> magic mistyped

Answer (score 3):

**N.B.** See [npostav's answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/36150/15748) for a better solution.

Sounds like you're looking for [`find-file-hook`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Visiting-Functions.html):

> `find-file-hook` is a variable defined in `files.el`.
>
> Its value is
>   `(global-eldoc-mode-check-buffers global-font-lock-mode-check-buffers epa-file-find-file-hook vc-refresh-state)`
>
> Original value was `nil`
>
> This variable may be risky if used as a file-local variable.
>
> Documentation:
>
> List of functions to be called after a buffer is loaded from a file.
>
> The buffer’s local variables (if any) will have been processed before the
>   functions are called.
>
> You can customize this variable.
>
> This variable was introduced, or its default value was changed, in
>   version 22.1 of Emacs.

In your case, for example:

```el
(defun my-rjsx-mode-check-buffers ()
  "Conditionally enable `rjsx-mode' based on file contents."
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (when (re-search-forward "^import .*react" nil t)
      (rjsx-mode))))

(add-hook 'find-file-hook #'my-rjsx-mode-check-buffers)
```

Comment: Note that if the file would normally be in Javascript mode by default, rather than add to `find-file-hook` a better option might be to add it to `js-mode-hook`.